# How to recursively remove a broken git remote from all repos in a directory?

Tags: git, git-remote

I have a folder full of old git repositories at arbitrary folder depths. Many of these repos were created when I was using an old git host that no longer exists. I need to find all of the local repos that reference that old remote and remove that remote from my local repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Linux:

```
find . -name .git -type d -prune -exec sh -c 'git --git-dir "{}" remote -v | grep bad.domain | cut -f1 | uniq | xargs -r -n 1 git --git-dir "{}" remote rm' \;
```

---

Windows PowerShell:

```
find . -name .git -type d -prune -exec sh -c 'git --git-dir ''{}'' remote -v | grep bad.domain | cut -f1 | uniq | xargs -r -n 1 git --git-dir ''{}'' remote rm' ";"
```

Escape sequences in Windows are weird...

---

How this works:

1. `find` all git repos in the current directory (look for `.git` folder)

   - `-prune` prevents `find` from recursing into found `.git` directories, improving performance
2. For each found repository, extract the remote `git ... remote -v`
3. `grep` for the `bad.domain`.
4. `cut` down to just the remote name
5. Filter duplicate remote names with `uniq`
6. Use `xargs` to run `git remote rm` for each found remote

   - `-r` means don't run `git remote rm` if no bad remotes were found on that repo
   - `-L 1` means run `git remote rm` once for each bad remote in a repository